# WPF ListView Star ("*") size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to fill the remaining area of a WPF `ListView` with a certain column.

I have been googling around and found the following solution:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Error" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ErrorDescription}" 
   Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
   AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Converter={StaticResource WidtConvert}} />
```

And the converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  ListView l = value as ListView;
  GridView g = l.View as GridView;
  double total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < g.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    total += g.Columns[i].ActualWidth;
  }
  return (l.ActualWidth - total);
}
```

But the problem is that at the time that the converter is called, all columns including the `ListView.ActualWidth` is 0.

I do not want to use any code behind for example on the `Listview_SizeChanged` etc.

Comment: Have you tried the solution from [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25058/ListView-Layout-Manager)?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the converter from code behind to Width property on Loaded event of ListView control.In that case the converter will get fired after the control will loaded completely and actual width get transfer to converter.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to bind the converter to the loaded property?

Comment: Sorry to reply so late.I found difficulty in having example with GridViewColumn.Another approach i will suggest that use multiconverter instead of converter and pass ListView.ActualHeight and the parameter used in converter as parameters.So the converter will be invoke after  ListView.ActualHeight changed from 0 to actual one.